# app_dev.php not always refreshing . How to contrain Netbeans/Browser to display freshest version of code?

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans

it's so annoying.

I'm working with Netbeans and Chrome (but other browers are not better) and i never know whether an error comes from last edited code or previosly edited.

app_dev.php suppose to take care of that, but its not.

I do not know whose cache is responsible for this: Netbeans, Symfony, Browsers.

How to contrain displaying latest version of my code?

---

edit

if do following steps its not work well:

1. physically delete cache (even command cache:clear --env=dev)
2. change code
3. refresh site

if do following steps its work well:

1. change code
2. physically delete cache (dev)
3. refresh site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans is an IDE. It will not cache any files I think. Try following this steps:

1. Use `Ctrl+F5` in Chrome to refresh the page with discarding the browser cache
2. Execute `php app/console cache:clear --env=dev` after each source code modification
3. Check your URL in browser address. It should be something like `http://localhost/web/app_dev.php`

Comment: i clicked as a good answear but it didn't help. I think that Netbeans is involved.

Answer (score 1):

@Olim pretty much covered it all. Only thing I would add is to try physically removing `cache` directory and running `cache:clear` again...

### EDIT:

I had numerous problems with access rights of my IDE (`phpStorm` in my case) which could not alter files stored in `Apache`'s default location (`C:\Program Files\Apache...`). The main cause was the dreaded Windows's `UAC` which prevented any program to write in some more sensitive locations.

To solve this you can either disable `UAC` or you could set the proper ownership:

- Right click on you project's directory
- Click `Properties`
- Click the `Security` tab, then `Advanced` button
- Switch to `Owner` tab and then `Edit` button
- Click `Other users and groups` and enter your username. Click `OK`
- Make sure you **check** the `Replace owner on ....`
- Restart all related software (`Netbeans`, `Chrome`, `Apache` service...)

Does it work now?

Comment: i did everything you both wrote and no better. Lets say i have 1.html and 2.html files,  I do changes in 2.html file. Refreshing browser, clearing symfony chache, opening 1.html in app_dev.php, clicking on the link to 2.html. And I see no changes in 2.html.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping you would say that! ;) I have updated the answer with suggestion...

Comment: i chose a faster way - disable UAC ( and restart OS), just to make sure whether it is effective in my PC. Unfortnatelly not. After that, every time I changing a code I need to DOUBLE refresh a page (with is funny) and I never can be sure whether it is sufficient. If I'm changing files 1.html and 2.html, sometimes there is updated view only for first opened file. The only 100% method till now is: changing code and physically delete cache (dev) files. It's no so bad, the key is that its reliable. Thank you for your time. (By the way. Im logged as a admin and project directory owner is admin too)